# Checking Optimization function whether its convex or not

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

The optimization function is defined as

$\frac{1}{2}.x^T.A.x$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & 1  
\end{pmatrix}$

How to check if this is a convex or not? I know about the second derivative test and it gives
$A$ which should be greater than $0$ in order to be convex but what are we really checking here? how is $A$ compared against $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check wheather $A$ (the hessian of the objetctive function $\frac{1}{2}x^T A x$) is positive semidefinit or not.
Here, $A$ is diagonally dominant and symmetric, which implies directly, that A is positive semidefinit, which implies, that your objective function $\frac{1}{2}x^T A x$ is convex.

Comment: what if I add a constraint to my function such that $x^T.A.x=23$? what will that mean? will it be still convex?

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^T A x$ is still convex but the feasible set is not convex any more, which makes optimization more difficult in general (your example is trivial since every x of the feasible set is a solution)

Comment: How did you test the feasible set for convexity? can you share more details?

Comment: The set $S:={x : x^T A x =c}$ for c>0 is an ellipse. A convex set C must contain all convex combinations $t x +(1-t)y$ for $x \element C$ and $y \element C$ and $0\leq t \leq 1$. So like a circle, an elipse is not convex but a disc is convex. As example without calculations choose $A=I_2$ the identity, and the constraint $x^T A x =1$. Then (1,0) and (0,1) fulfil the condition but the convex combination (1/2,1/2) does not.

Comment: But the set $S:=\{x: x^T Ax \leq 1 \}$ is convex since this is the area in the elllipse so every connecting line lies into it.